# Facebook Graph API. Как достать информацию о публичной странице?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Необходимо из каждой страницы, найденной в поиске, достать адрес электронной почты, адрес сайта, телефон, инстаграм, страну и город.
Почему-то в версии Graph API 2.4+ при запросе `get /{page-id}` и `/{page-id}?fields=field1...` не возвращается ничего, кроме `id`.

Как можно достать эти данные, когда у нас есть `id` страницы?

Answer (score 0):

Это политика Facebook (а также Instagram и Whats App) в отношении своих API. Там все сильно ограничено по доступным методам, а на существующие наложены существенные ограничения (особенно, что касается личных данных).

В вашем случае, чтобы получить информацию о пользователе, ему необходимо передать вашему приложению права на доступ к своей информации (такое окно, когда вы пытаетесь авторизоваться на каком-нибудь сайте или привязать свой аккаунт).

Можно собирать общедоступную информацию также через прямые запросы к сайту (но там надо быть аккуратнее с User Agent и таймингами запросов) или использовать Facebook Private API, по которому их официальное приложение передает информацию на мобильные клиенты.

Comment: Под публичной страницей я имел в виду страницу какой-нибудь организации, что-то вроде этого: https://www.facebook.com/THESLOVENIA/  Я исползовал Graph API Explorer для того, чтобы проверить работоспособность запросов. Там я выставил все галочки при получении токена доступа. Скраппинг не подходит: нужно много страниц обработать. О Facebook Private API не нашел информации.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer там выдается информация или нет? если нет, то дело скорее всего в политике facebook, тут только private api поможет. что касается информации о нем - естественно ее нет в открытом доступе, а то немногое что есть обычно сильно устарело и может не работать. используйте реверсинг приложения facebook для android, смотрите нужные вам методы и пишите соответствующий код (там все не сильно отличается от graph api, но небольшие отличия есть).

Comment: Где описание Facebook Private API и либы?